# Azure Web App is running but also is deleted

Tags: azure, web

I am facing the above problem. I created and i deleted 3 times a Web App + Mysql in Azure with the same name.

Now it seems that the application is running in App Services Tab but its status it is deleted. So I can not do anything (Restart Delete Customize etc)

Can I do something with the azure command line in order to delete the Web App permanently? Or Any other ideas?

Tnx

Comment: Probably you just need to wait a while for some cache to clear. Try opening a new Incognito/InPrivate session and see if that clears it.

Comment: Yes it worked. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could, use PowerShell to do that. `Remove-AzureRmWebApp`

Comment: i did not try it, but it worked with the cache as juunas mentioned before. Thank you for your answer.